# Setting UISearchBar placeholder alignment to NSTextAlignmentLeft

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I am trying to set the placeholder text alignment in Objective-C or Swift for iOS 9 and above. I have tried the following:
1.

```
for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
    for(id field in subview.subviews) {
        if ([field isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            [(UITextField*)field setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
        }
    }
}
```

2.

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
```

3.

```
UITextField *searchTextField = [self valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
UILabel *placeholderLabel = [searchTextField valueForKey:@"_placeholderLabel"];
[placeholderLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
```

4. ```
   self.searchBar?.searchTextPositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: -100, vertical: 0)
   ```

But none of these have worked. Is there something else that I am missing? The view debugger shows that the textfield is centered, but changing its frame also has not been working for me.

Comment: Do you use auto layout?

Comment: No this is all created programmatically, and the view debugger shows no constraints on the searchbar or the placeholder textfield

Comment: @RDSpinz have you checked "setSearchTextPositionAdjustment" property of searchbar?

Comment: Yes, that only affects the text while you are searching. I want the placeholder text when not searching to be left aligned

Comment: @RDSpinz have you found any solution to this yet?

Comment: No, I ended up sticking with left align due to time constraints. It may be possible by making a custom navigation and search control, but afaik this is not doable in a simple default manner